# Jenkins job should receive deployment status from Spinnaker pipeline (success/error)

Tags: jenkins, spinnaker

I am new to use the spinnaker. I have set up the spinnaker with the helm chart in my k8s cluster. Everything is working fine. Now I have a new requirement to set up the notification for the spinnaker pipeline (Success/failure). But the requirement is tricky. 
I read out about Spinnaker and Jenkins to post the success/failure status. Spinnaker has a notification mechanism to notify for each stage/pipeline about success/failure. We can set up this notification. Jenkins has the same mechanism. But the question is when the spinnaker pipeline successfully completed then it triggers the Jenkins job to post the spinnaker pipeline status on the portal. I have created a Jenkins stage that is successful triggers the Jenkins job but it is not catching the status or events from the spinnaker pipeline. In case, job spinnaker pipeline failed, it will not trigger the Jenkins to post the failure message. I tried to find out the solution but unable to do it. If anyone knows how to fix this issue, Please guide me or write me the solution in detail here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create Jenkins stage in the same pipeline which you are monitoring. You can create additional Pipeline in Spinnaker which receive trigger from target pipeline. All you need is configure trigger in that new pipeline:

```
  "triggers": [
    {
      "application": "demo-app",
      "enabled": true,
      "pipeline": "demo-pipe",
      "status": [
        "successful",
        "failed"
      ],
      "type": "pipeline"
    }
  ]
```

You can extract required information (e.g. status) about upstream pipeline from this trigger.

If `post the pipeline status on the internal portal` in your terms means to send an HTTP Request than you should consider a [Webhook Stage](https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/pipeline/stages/#webhook).

In runtime you have whole parent pipeline context in your downstream and can get it status with expression like `${trigger.parentExecution.status}` to provide it in your request.

Comment: In the additional pipeline, Do I need to use the Jenkins stage to post the pipeline status on the internal portal? Also, what configuration I needed in Jenkin's side to pick the exact message from the target pipeline? In case my spinnaker pipeline is successful, how can I display a success message in the additional pipeline? and the same about failure or canceled case? Please clear about it.
Thanks.

Comment: @MuhammadWaseemAlvi see updates in answer. For Jenkins job it is just input parameter. You can use Check Preconditions Stage to validate required fields.